# org.json.JSONException: No value for comments

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I have a Json data that i am getting from a wordpress blog and when i tried passing the url I get this error in my logcat saying **org.json.JSONException: No value for comments.**

what am trying to do is retrieve commments from a wordpress blog.

I have pasted my full code [here](http://pastebin.com/eezNMHjj) for further references,

```
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926): org.json.JSONException: No value for comments
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at com.cepfmobileapp.org.CommentActivityWp$GetQuery.doInBackground(CommentActivityWp.java:271)
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at com.cepfmobileapp.org.CommentActivityWp$GetQuery.doInBackground(CommentActivityWp.java:1)
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-13 11:43:59.698: W/System.err(18926):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-13 11:43:59.708: W/System.err(18926):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-13 11:43:59.708: W/System.err(18926):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-13 11:43:59.708: W/System.err(18926):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-13 11:43:59.708: W/System.err(18926):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Java Code

```
    private static final String TAG_COMMENTS = "comments";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";


    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    ida = i.getStringExtra("id");
    url = "" + ida;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                comments = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_COMMENTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < comments.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = comments.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                     //JSONObject comments = c.getJSONObject(TAG_COMMENTS );
                     String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                     String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                     String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    queryList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Did u checked your response ?

Comment: Your `comments` array is resides under your `posts` arraylist so you will have to access it from the `posts` arraylist only.

Comment: @kunu yes, no data was displayed and then i got this comment in my logcat saying org.json.JSONException: No value for comments

Comment: @GrlsHu can you show me how to go about this

Comment: Can you post your response format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
     try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            comments = jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < comments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = comments.getJSONObject(i);

                //get the comments arraylist
                 JSONArray commentsdata = c.getJSONArray(TAG_COMMENTS);
                      for (int j = 0; j < commentsdata.length(); j++) 
                        {
                            JSONObject comntObj = commentsdata.getJSONObject(j);
                          String name = comntObj.getString("name");
                          String sUrl = comntObj.getString("url");
                           String scontent = comntObj.getString("content");
                        ....................

                       }
                  String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                 String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);


                // adding contact to contact list
                queryList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @GrlsHu, i will do this and get back to you, thank you so much

Comment: @GrIsHu **posts** is `JSONObject` but your getting as `JSONArray` Is that right?

Comment: @Hariharan No its `JSONArray` only. Have you checked response??

Comment: @GrIsHu check out the JSON link http://www.cepfonline.org/cepfblog/?json=1&p=33223264

Comment: @Hariharan Check out link http://www.cepfonline.org/cepfblog/?json=1=test I have given answer based on this response.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working now, yipeeeeee, just one more thing how can i post a comment to a blog in wordpress

Comment: @m.opeyemi You're Welcome dear. Glad to help always. :)

Comment: Are you asking to post comment on php ?

Comment: Nooo, this json am getting is from a wordpress blog, i would also like to post a comment to the blog

Comment: @m.opeyemi Well i haven't worked on this for posting comments on wordpress. Better you google it.

Comment: okay, i really appreciate you, am better because of people like you. thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: @m.opeyemi Glad to Help always. :)

Answer (score 4):

Ty this..

There is no `comments` in your JSONArray in your response you have to check with `jsonObj.has(TAG_CONTENT)` that TAG name present or not.

```
JSONObject  jsonpost= jsonObj.getJSONObject("post");
if(jsonpost.has(TAG_ID)){

    comments = jsonpost.getJSONArray(TAG_COMMENTS);

    for (int i = 0; i < comments.length(); i++) {   

    String id = "";
    String name = "";
    String content = "";

    if(c.has(TAG_ID))
       id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

    if(c.has(TAG_NAME))
      name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

    if(c.has(TAG_CONTENT))
       content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONObject  jsonpost= jsonObj.getJSONObject("post");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonpost.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = jsonpost.getJSONObject(i);

                     JsonArray comments=c.getJSONArray("comments");
                    for (int j = 0; j< comments.size();j++) {
                        JSONObject jj = comments.getJSONObject(j);

                     String id = jj.getString(TAG_ID);
                     String name = jj.getString(TAG_NAME);
                     String content = jj.getString(TAG_CONTENT);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    queryList.add(contact);
                }
            }
```

I hope its useful to you..

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    JSONObject  jsonpost= jsonObj.getJSONObject("post");
    comments = jsonpost.getJSONArray("comments");
    ...........................................
    //your rest codes//
}
```

Your `comments` is a JSONArray which inside `post` JSONObject. So you need to access `comments` from `post` JSONObject.